# Encode binary file into php page

Tags: php

I want to encode binary file into base64 and put it into php page (inline with the code), And when request that page it streams the file to the browser,popup a download dialog.

Any ideas

Comment: Well it's `print base64_decode('02FAF....');` and not workable if that file is larger than the memory available to your PHP interpreter.

Comment: Mario, post this usegul answer not as a comment but an answer itself :)

Comment: @mario Thank you, What if the file is large, is there any way to stream it?

Comment: Yes. Store the binary data in a separate file then.

Comment: It's clear now, Thank you very much @mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward. As with [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), use http headers to force download, and then echo the encoded string.

```
$decoded_data = base64_decode($encoded_data);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($decoded_data);
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $decoded_data;
exit;
```

Comment: I won't downvote you for this immediately, but if you don't fix it I might... You have decoded the string twice, once to get the length of the data and once to output it. You should store the result of `base64_decode()` in variable, and pass the variable to `strlen()` and `echo` - what if the data was 100MB?

Comment: Good point. I still wouldn't recommend this for big files, because the whole file is loaded into memory, but at least this way it's only decoded once.

Comment: I personally wouldn't *recommend* it at all, there is almost no reason to do this. I admit it's potentially nice to make a whole application contained within one file (which is the only legitimate reason I can think of for doing this) but the small aesthetic gain vs the large performance cost makes it not really viable. But your answer is good, if a little over engineered - The caching headers would be better set towards client caching, since the string is static in the script and there is a large overhead in serving the file, and FYI there is no such HTTP header as `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example can help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#105200

Regards!